# return first element from array as computed property from Ember controller subclass

Tags: javascript, arrays, model-view-controller, ember.js

I am trying to return the first element of my array as a computed property to my template from my controller. My code is below. I am 100% about my array and template. Problem is my syntax about in the controller. 
Basically my array is works made of Work objects. And I would ideally return the first element Work. Is that even possible in javascript?

Best.

//controller works.js

```
import Ember from "ember";
  export default Ember.Controller.extend({
  firstElement: function () {
    var arr = this.get('model');
    return arr[0];
    console.log(arr[0]);
  }.property('Work')
});
```

//template works.js

```
<div class="right">
  {{#liquid-with model as |currentModel|}}
    {{firstElement}}
  {{/liquid-with}}
</div>
```

//route works.js

```
import Ember from 'ember';

var Work = Ember.Object.extend({
  name: '',
  year: '',
  description:'',
  image:'',
  logo:'',

  work_id: function() {
    return this.get('name').dasherize();
  }.property('name'),


});

var minibook = Work.create({
  id: 1,
  name: 'MINIBOOK',
  year: '2014',
  description:'MiniBook is an iphone app that explores storytelling in its own format. The format',
  image:'assets/images/minibook_iphone.png',
  logo:'assets/images/minibook_logo.png'
});

var poetics = Work.create({
  id: 2,
  name: 'POETICS',
  year: '2013',
  description:'Lorem Ipsum Poetics',
  image:'assets/images/poetics_iphone.png',
  logo:'assets/images/poetics_logo.png'
});


var WorksCollection = Ember.ArrayProxy.extend(Ember.SortableMixin, {
  sortProperties: ['id'],
  sortAscending: true,
  content: []
 });


var works = WorksCollection.create();

works.pushObjects([poetics, minibook]);


export default Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    return works;
  }


});
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This would work.

**Long way** (just to improve your computed property code):

```
// controller work.js
import Ember from "ember";
export default Ember.Controller.extend({
  firstElement: function () {
    return this.get('model').get('firstObject'); // or this.get('model.firstObject'); 
  }.property('model.[]')
});
```

1) you set `works` as `model` in route, so you could get it as `model` in controller

2) `.property(model.[])` means computed property on array, so adding and deleting array element will fire update. You could also choose some specific property i.e. `.property(model.@each.modelProperty)`

3) `fistObject` is proper method (not `[0]`), since you are working with Ember.ArrayProxy, see http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.ArrayProxy.html

4) you could use {{firstElement}} in template

**Lazy way**:

1) set model in route as array or as promise resolved in array

```
// works = ... as is
export default Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    return works;
  }
});
```

2) get `model.firstObject` in directly in template

```
//template works
{{model.firstObject}} {{!-- first object of model array --}}
{{model.firstObject.name}}  {{!-- name of first object --}}
```

UPDATE:
    use proper iteration syntax http://ef4.github.io/liquid-fire/#/helpers/liquid-with/10

```
{{#liquid-with model as currentModel}}
  {{currentModel.firstObject.name}}
{{/liquid-with}}
```

Comment: thanks so much for your detailed answer. I learned a lot just reading that response and I am tempted to accept it as true answer. However, when I try each ways I am getting <(unknown mixin):ember562> error in my template where I put the  {{firstElement}} or {{model.firstObject}} respectively. It's most probably not your fault :) Here's my gist for the complete works.hbs just in case. I would appreciate any directions.

Comment: In the lazy way, do I have to make any changes to my route? Your 1) looks identical to how I return the array currently. Am I missing something? Thank you so much again.

Comment: your iterations look strange, I need to google how {{#liquid-with}} works

Comment: hey I made it work. apparently I had to do  {{firstElement.name}} to get rid off the unknown mixin error. liquid-with is just liquid fire to bring animations really. Thanks so much!

Comment: TLDR; Just use `.get('firstObject')` when accessing ember data objects to get the first item of an array

Answer (score 2):

A bit more updated (or different) example

```
import Controller from '@ember/controller';
import { readOnly } from '@ember/object/computed';

export default Controller.extend({
  firstElement: readOnly('model.firstObject')
});
```

Or if you want bidirectional data flow (can set `firstElement`)

```
import Controller from '@ember/controller';
import { alias } from '@ember/object/computed';

export default Controller.extend({
  firstElement: alias('model.firstObject')
});
```